# Find the sum of values inside a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I have a nested array that looks like this:

```
let scores = [  
[[2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0]],  
[[4, 2, 0]],  
[[4, 2, 0]],  
[[4, 2, 0],[2, 1, 0]]  
]
```

What I'm trying to do is get the highest value of each array (and sum the highest values in arrays that contain more than one array, ie. inside the first array, [[2,1,0],[2,1,0]], I need to sum the highest values of each array which in this case is 2+2.)
My thought is to shift() the first value of each array OR slice()/remove the lower values so my array looks like this:
`newScores = [[[2],[2]], [4], [4], [[4],[2]]]`

Ultimately, my desired output is: `output = [[4], [4], [4], [6]]`

Hope someone can provide some direction! Thanks!

Comment: On StackOverflow you are expected to at least try and solve the problem yourself first and show some code and what problem you are having.  Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: If you seek guidance you can look at [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: Hi @Dijkgraaf, I totally understand. I wanted to include what I've tried so far but I've ran through using .reduce and looping and .map and nothing is coming close to what I'm trying to achieve, so didn't think showing my severely failed attempts would help anyone, haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate of the parent array, then for each array in that - iterate over its arrays, getting the max number from each array - then summing the children arrays and finally pushing the totals into the output array.

```js
let scores = [  
[[2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0]],  
[[4, 2, 0]],  
[[4, 2, 0]],  
[[4, 2, 0],[2, 1, 0]]  
]

var output = [];
scores.forEach(function(score) {
  var total = 0
  score.forEach(function(arr) {
    total += arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return Math.max(a, b); }); 
  })
  output.push(total);
})

console.log(output); // gives [4,4,4,6]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 const result = scores.map(groups =>
     groups.map((sum, group) => sum + Math.max(...group), 0)
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `map()`, `reduce()` and `Math.max` methods and spread syntax `...`.

```js
let scores = [  
  [[2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0]],  
  [[4, 2, 0]],  
  [[4, 2, 0]],  
  [[4, 2, 0],[2, 1, 0]]  
]  

const result = scores.map(a => a.reduce((r, e) => {
  return +r + Math.max(...e)
}, []))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let scores = [  
[[2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 0]],  
[[4, 2, 0]],  
[[4, 2, 0]],  
[[4, 2, 0],[2, 1, 0]]  
]

function nestedArray(arr){
   let result=[];
   let counter = 0;
   for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
       if(arr[i].length>1){
           var a = [Math.max(...arr[i][counter])];
           var b = [Math.max(...arr[i][counter+1])];
        result.push(a.map((ax,bx)=>ax+b[bx]));
       }
       if(arr[i].length===1){
            result.push([Math.max(...arr[i][counter])]);

       }


   }
   return result;

}
nestedArray(scores);
```

Comment: This code works  if the nested array length less than 3,  it works perfectly fine with nested array length less than or equal to 2. we need to loop if the nested array length is  more than 2.